# ttk::spinbox with tk_messageBox causes infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tk-toolkit, ttk

Seems to be a problem with ttk::spinbox. I am using Python 3.5.2, Tk 8.6 on Windows 7.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class Spinbox(Widget):
  def __init__(self, master, **kw):
    super().__init__(master, 'ttk::spinbox', kw)

def cb1():
  print('--> cb1()')

def cb2():
  showinfo('cb2', '--> cb2()')

root = Tk()
spin1 = Spinbox(root, from_ = 0, to = 10, command = cb1).pack()
spin2 = Spinbox(root, from_ = 0, to = 10, command = cb2).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I click the up or down arrow on the spin2 spinbox, it pops up the messagebox dialog as expected, but then after clicking OK the up/down arrow seems to repeatedly fire and keep in/decrementing the value, causing the messagebox dialog to be displayed over and over. The only way to quit seems to be killing the process (end task). This infinite loop behavior does not occur with spin1, which just prints a message to the console when an arrow is clicked. It also does not happen if the classic Tk spinbox is used instead.

Probably not a whole lot of real-life use cases for doing this, but I uncovered it while using showinfo for debugging. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround/fix?

Comment: on some platforms, mouse clicks "bleed through" to the underlying window when using the messagebox.